# No homotopy with the identity of the unit circle

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, retraction

> Let $Y\subset S^{1}$ be a proper subspace of the unit circle. Prove that does not exists any homotopy $F$ between $\operatorname{id}_{S^{1}}$ and $i\circ f$, where $f: S^{1}\rightarrow Y$ is any continuous function and $i$ denotes the inclusion

Although I see that, I'm stuck with this exercise. By contraddiction, we would have a continuous function
$$F:I\times S^{1}\rightarrow S^{1}$$
such that
$$F(0,x) = x,$$ and
$$F(1,x) = i(f(x))\in Y.$$
If $Y =\{ x_{0}\}$ we would have a retraction, hence it couldn't be since $S^{1}$ is not contractible.
The problem come up when I consider the case $Y\neq \{ x_{0}\}$ and I can't see how to conclude. Can someone help me? Thanks before.

Comment: Do you already know about the fundamental group and its induced homomorphisms? That is the easiest way to do this problem.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins we would have maps $f_{*}:\pi _{1}(S^{1})\rightarrow \pi_{1}(Y)$ and $i_{*}:\pi _{1}(Y)\rightarrow \pi_{1}(S^{1})$ such that $(i\circ f)_{*}=\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{Z}}$, which can't be since $Y$ is homeomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and then its fundamental group is trivial. Right?

Comment: This has been asked before. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4840899/857096

Comment: @Julius Not precisely. In the linked question it is required that $f$ is a retraction.

Comment: @Dungessio that's basically it. Check for understanding: what is $i_*$ explicitly?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins the trivial homomorphism. Since $\pi_{1}(Y)$ is trivial, we have explicitly $i_{*}:\{ 0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: That's it. The rest of the proof is trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to komw that $S^1$ is not contractible.

Since $Y$ is a proper subspace of $S^1$, there exists $Z \in S^1$ such that $Y \subset U_z = S^1 \setminus \{z\}$. The set $U_z$ is homeomorphic to an open interval, hence contractible.

Let $j :  U_z \to S^1$ be the inclusion. Define
$$f' : S^1 \xrightarrow{f} Y \hookrightarrow U_z .$$
Then $j \circ f' = i \circ f$.

Since $U_z$ is contractble, the map $j \circ f'$ is homotopic to a constant map, thus the same is true for  $i \circ f$.

This excludes $i \circ f \simeq id$ because that would mean that $S^1$ is contractible.